# Better way of debugging when logging is not implemented in critical code statements

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recently I came across a situation where I was not able to understand what a variable is getting assigned or whether a thread has got any exception since it was in a catch block and no logging was implemented for the stacktrace as it is a old codebase I can obviously find out such critical sections then implement logging but since it is a large codebase it gets difficult also I cant take remote debug since code is running in production is there any solution available for this!

Comment: Use a breakpoint right before it and debug it?

Comment: I cant as it is on Production and I am not allowed to take remote debug

Comment: So you can't modify the code either?  Why can't you test the same code on the QA version or something.

Comment: We tested the code on QC but it ended up it missed a couple test cases and went on production

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *Java Profile*r for example *YourKit*.

> The YourKit profiler is one of the most established leaders among Java
>   profilers. As a mature and a versatile profiler, YourKit can do both
>   CPU and memory profiling for you, with integrations across major Java
>   application servers, JDBC and other frameworks for high-level
>   performance analysis like finding synchronization issues and excessive
>   database accesses. YourKit can run in both sampling and tracing
>   profiling modes, and the mixed approach helps it make the most from
>   both worlds: the precision of tracing the actual code execution while
>   being able to precisely control the profiling overhead.
>   [source](https://jrebel.com/rebellabs/top-5-java-profilers-revealed-real-world-data-with-visualvm-jprofiler-java-mission-control-yourkit-and-custom-tooling/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to apply tracing. Typically, mission critical applications require that application code is covered with tracing statements, e.g.:

```
logger.entering(className, methodName, args);
```

Each method needs to trace its entry / return as well as intermediate work. Implementing tracing manually is error prone and costly, it may easily account for 20% of all code. For production code, applications apply tracing specification to filter which code is logged, so performance impact is minimal: *=all:com.company.MyClass.*=finer

To easily enable your Java application for tracing and avoid writing tracing code, use the **enterprise-aspects** AOP Java library:
https://github.com/akovac35/enterprise-aspects